How to Write a WordPress React Plugin With Multiple Shortcodes and Different Parameters?
I am writing a Wordpress plugin with React. The plugin needs to offer multiple shortcodes. Each shortcode displays its own React component, all within the same React app. The plugin also needs to let you add the same shortcode multiple times, but with different attributes. Attributes are passed as properties to each respective React component. Like this:
[shortcode_1 a=1 b=2] => <Component1 a=1 b=2 />
[shortcode_1 a=3 b=4] => <Component1 a=3 b=4 />
[shortcode_2 c=5 d=6] => <Component2 c=5 d=6 />

Resulting in:
<ReactApp>
  <Component1 a=1 b=2 />
  <Component1 a=3 b=4 />
  <Component2 c=5 d=6 />
</ReactApp>

So far, I have only been trying to handle the case of multiple shortcodes. I have not yet attempted to handle the same shortcode multiple times. What I've tried is essentially the following, but I can't figure out how to handle passing the attributes to React. In the browser debugger, when I print window.parameters, it's undefined. What is the recommended way to do this?
<?php

$parameters = array();

function shortcode_1( $atts = [] ) { 

    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'a' => '1',
            'b' => '2'
        ), $atts
    );
    
    $GLOBALS['parameters']['shortcode_1'] = $data;
}

function shortcode_2( $atts = [] ) { 

    $data = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'a' => '3',
            'b' => '4'
        ), $atts
    );
    
    $GLOBALS['parameters']['shortcode_2'] = $data;
}


add_shortcode('shortcode_1', 'shortcode_1');
add_shortcode('shortcode_2', 'shortcode_2');

function add_parameters() {
    wp_localize_script( 'react-app', 'parameters', $GLOBALS['parameters'] );
}

function add_react_app() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
                <div id="react-root"></div>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enq_react');

function enq_react(){
    wp_register_script(
        'react-app',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/dist/main.js',
        ['wp-element'],
        rand(), // Change this to null for production
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'react-app' );

    add_react_app();
}
?>

